# create method for calHighestAvg(cityRain)

Tags: java

How to do the code for calHighestAvg

```
public class City {

    private String cityName;
    private double[] monhtlyRain = new double[12];
     //constructor  
    //processor to return the average of the current year  

    public double yearlyRainAvg()

    public double calHighestAvg()
    //getters  
    //toString  
}

public class cityRainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        City[] cityRain = new City[20];
        //input  
        System.out.println("The city with the highest of rain for this year :");
        City highestCity = calHighestAvg(cityRain); //can't understand this  
        System.out.println(highestCity.toString());
    }
}
```

I cannot find a way to do method for calHighestAvg(cityRain)

Comment: use the code formatting tools StackOverflow has, it greatly helps. also look into using loops. good luck on your assignment.

Comment: Get data, and calculate the average? What *specifically* are you having an issue with? Nobody here is going to hand you the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to "calHighestAvg" will never work as is - because you have one method in your City class and you are attempting to call another unwritten method (with the same name) from your main cityRainApp class. One returns a double and the other is supposed to return a City.

The way to go about this is to implement your unwritten calHighestAvg method (change your method names to be less confusing!!) that returns a City in your main program (inside the cityRainApp class). With a changed name, inside your cityRainApp class, it should look something like this:

```
public City highestAvg(City[] cityRain) {
    double highestRain = cityRain[0].calHighestAvg();
    City highestRainCity = cityRain[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < cityRain.length; ++i) {
        double currAvg = cityRain[i].calHighestAvg();
        if (currAvg > highestRain) {
            highestRain = currAvg;
            highestRainCity = cityRain[i]
        }
    }
    return highestRainCity;
}
```